# What does density means here?

Tags: meaning

Someone said that someone has the right emotional density and I can't figure if it means he's a deep person or what

Comment: It's not a precise technical term, but depends on interpretation.

Comment: Presumably "the right emotional density" involves having not too much and not too little.

Comment: @Henry but what is emotional density

Comment: Is it possible you misheard "emotional intensity"? I've never heard the expression "emotional density".

Comment: It means what the writer intended it to mean, in a Humpty-Dumpty Through the Looking Glass sense.  A brief search found [one example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/26166542) applies it to story-telling and presumably it represents what proportion involved emotions rather than events or other components.  [Another example on psychology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8572316/pdf/nihms-1702541.pdf) seems to take a quantitative approach estimating how much current emotions are influenced by previous emotions.

Comment: In what context?